# Is it possible to transfer parameter's from one react-native application to another react-native application?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-navigation

Am trying to pass parameter from one react-native application to another react-native application. I know it is possible & did it well in Android, but just want to know about how it will be done in react-native.

One caller application let's say Param_send_App, Param_receive_app.

From Param_send_App I will call `Linking.openURL('param_receive_app://app?param1=test&param2=test2')`
but how Will I receive the param in Param_receive_app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well,
It's really easy, got the answer by that day itself when question was posted.
As u can pass the param from **Param_send_App**
to **Param_receive_app**

```
Linking.getInitialURL().then((url) => {
                if (url) {
                    console.log(url);
                }
                else {
                    console.log("No Parameter found, perform any other operation");
                }
            }).catch(err => console.error('Silently capture the error', err));
```

But there's one more thing to do
Inside the AndroidManifest.xml add

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="param_receive_app" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="com.param_receive_app" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Where `param_receive_app` is just package name which is necessary.

Comment: Rushabh Gendam can you explain me what do in Param_receive_app !

Answer (score -1):

You could use React Navigation to handle them: [Configuring links](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/configuring-links/)

Comment: No, navigation is for passing params within the app, The question is about passing params from one app to another